# Does SQL Server use a symmetric key under the hood while encrypting backups?

Tags: sql-server, encryption, backup

SQL Server 2016 uses AES-256 **symmetric** encryption algorithm for backups. However, it uses an **asymmetric** key in conjunction with AES-256.

As we know, asymmetric keys are not designed for encrypting large amounts of data.

Does the system, under the hood, generate a sort of a symmetric session key and encrypt data with that, then protects this session key with the above mentioned asymmetric one?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's what it basically does. From [Backup Encryption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449489.aspx), bold is mine:

> To encrypt during backup, you must specify an encryption algorithm,
> and an encryptor **to secure the encryption key**. The following are the
> supported encryption options:
>
> - Encryption Algorithm: The supported encryption algorithms are: AES 128, AES 192, AES 256, and Triple DES
> - Encryptor: A certificate or asymmetric Key

Since nowhere in the process you have to enter the encryption password, it is safe to assume that one is generated on the fly and then encrypted using an asymmentric algorithm.

Comment: That leaves the question of where/how is the asymmetric key is securely stored.

Comment: @zaph, in the `master` database, with their private keys being encrypted by database master key. Just like any other certificate or asymmetric key stored in SQL Server. And if you need to restore the encrypted backup on another instance, you have to transfer this cert / asym key there, manually.

Comment: Moving along, how is the database master key key secret?

Comment: I think I know where this is going :). Here is a (relatively) good starting point: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189586.aspx

Comment: OK, here is where it is going: Where is the "top key" stored, on disk? If on disk it is equally available to an administrator and an attacker who has gain admin privileged in some manner. The exception being an HSM or equivalent used to store or encrypt the key. Unless the encryption/decryption is performed by an HSM or equivalent it is in RAM during use and vulnerable. None of this is to say encryption is not useful but that one must be aware that the secrecy problem has just moved to the key and the key storage must be considered, "hand waving" is not enough.

Comment: @zaph, Well, cert's PVK is protected by DMK (from master database, in this case), which is normally protected by SMK and / or password, but you can turn off the SMK part. In this case, in order to open the master DMK and perform encrypted backup / restore you will need its password, simply being sysadmin is not enough. There might be other attack vectors I'm not aware of, though, because I have never designed systems that anal on security. You better to play with the stuff yourself for a while and see if you can beat it.

Comment: Also, the SMK is protected by the Data Protection API of the Windows Server hosting the instance. It is protected in two ways, first using the local machine key and second using the service account running the instance.